# Remove partial duplicates sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am altering an existing view within SQL Server. My union statement creates something along the lines of:

```
     Col1 | C2 | C3   | C4
     -----|----|------|-----
1      A  | B  | NULL | NULL
2      A  | B  |  C   | NULL
3      A  | B  |  C   |  D
4      E  | F  | NULL | NULL
5      E  | F  |  G   | NULL
```

However, I only want (in this scenario) rows 3 and 5 (I need to ommit one and two because they contain duplicate info - columns one, two, and three contain the same info as row three, but the third row is the most 'complete'). Row 5 for the same reason vs row 4.

Is this an outer join / intersect issue? How the heck do you create a view in this manner?

Comment: Be clear with what u are asking!! you have said i need to omit one and two but there is no 2nd row!! there are totally 5 rows then which one to consider as 6th row??

Comment: You could look into ranking your result set. Rank and Dense_rank.

Comment: @Pradeep - fair enough!  Sorry about that... Copy/paste error on my part. All fixed up now.

Comment: You say this is a view--can you show the query underlying the view, or is that relevant? Do we need only treat the data shown as a table and write a query against it? Next: do all the columns allow nulls, or only some?

Comment: I have a stored procedure that I have written against it. I just need the table to be streamlined. I only want the query to use the most 'complete' version of the data (the other rows have become inconsequential). All columns allow nulls. As a matter of fact, the control I am using that issues the query will quit when it hits a null, that is why I need to use the rows that are most streamlined.

Comment: With no (known) constraints on the data, how do you determine how to combine data? For example, if the data (based on your second sample) looked like the following, how would you want it rolled up: (layout fails in comment boxes, and ~ represents NULL):  E/F/~/~   E/F/G/~   E/F/G/H   E/F/G/I   ~/F/G/J

Comment: The current view is a flat table which was going to be used to create a tree. So... I can have E/F/~/~, E/F/G/~, E/F/G/H. I now just need the last of those three to traverse for this tree. Basically, I want to create a flat table that represents each node of the tree to its fullest. Not sure if that makes sense or not...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Col1 is not NULL, then we can use ROW_NUMBER with order by on all 4 columns total value

```
; with cte 
AS
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over ( partition by col1 order by (coalesce(Col1,'')+ 
         coalesce([C2],'') + 
         coalesce([C3],'') + 
         coalesce([C4],'') ) desc) as seq,
         *
FROM Table1
)
 select * from cte
 where seq =1
```